# Is there an easy way to get a single folder out of a Deja-Dup backup?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

When I installed 11.10, I manually moved my data. Unfortunately, I forgot to move ~/.shotwell. I have a recent Deja-Dup backup of my home directory (minus a few things like ~/.thumbnails and so on). Is there an easy way to get the .shotwell folder from it? I'd rather not uncompress a 70 GB backup.

Thanks!

Comment: Switch to using `rsync` and it is easy.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>*I don't actually have a backup at hand, so I'm not 100% sure if that works for folders as well..*</sub>

If you right-click in nautilus in your home folder there's an option *Restore Missing Files...* which can be used to restore individual folders.

[image: Restore Missing Files... entry in the context menu.]

Comment: There is no such option (Ubuntu 15.04) for me. How do I get it?